# How do I solve the puzzles in the Immaculates Trial?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

There are a series of puzzles in the Immaculates trial and I seem to be stuck.

I'm at the point where there are 4 pressure plates on the ground and a doorway that has a barrier on it.  How do I solve this puzzle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the weight of items matters when placed on the pressure plates.

The heaviest item should go on the biggest plate and the lightest should go on the smallest plate.  When the correct weight is on the plate, you will hear/see a *click* and one of the barriers will go down.

In that area, there is a heavy barrel, a regular vase, and a few books.

The heavy barrel goes on the biggest plate, the regular vase goes on the second biggest plate, the book (weight 1) goes on the smallest plate.  I couldn't find anything to go on the last plate, but I stacked a few items totaling weight 2 onto it and it clicked.

Comment: I did it with a barrel on the biggest, vase on the second, the bucket of water you find in the secret room on the third, and burning candles on the last.

Comment: @Lyrion I must've missed the secret room.

Comment: Ha no worries I missed it too, it was my coop partner that found it :p. The great thing about this game is that 2 different views are better then 1.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that any object placed on any pressure button has to equal 100% for it to work (enhanced version of game??). If you are under 100% or over, then it doesn't seem to work.

I found the heavy barrel for the largest button (100%), a bucket of water for the medium sized button, and a book for the smallest. This worked to drop the barrier.